# How do I add a url in embed.add_field discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make it so I can have different URLs on different areas of an embed, is there a way to do this in `embed.add_field`?

My code:

```
@bot.command()
async def status(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Bot Status", color=ctx.author.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed.add_field(name="replit.com", url="https://Eternalia-Development.malakaishryock.repl.co")
    embed.add_field(name="betteruptime.com", url="https://eternalia-na.betteruptime.com/")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Whenever I run the command `!status`, I get the error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: add_field() got an unexpected keyword argument 'url'`

Comment: Yes, it is formatted, Stackoverflow just didn't put it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mika Tan's answer should work fine, however if you want your link to be a hyperlink like '[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66683215/how-do-i-add-a-url-in-embed-add-field-discord-py)'.
Use

```py
embed.add_field(name="replit.com", value="[Here is the link](url)")
```

Comment: I can't seem to get `replit.com` to display as the hyperlink. Is there a way to remove it using a 0-width whitespace character then just put `value="[replit.com](url)"`? I have heard of a character like this, but I don't know what it is or if it even works in `""` in the `name` value.

Comment: Then don't add it as a separate field, just use it in the description

Answer (score 0):

There is no url value for an embed field. Instead of using url, use value.

Like this:

```
embed.add_field(name="replit.com",value = "https://Eternalia-Development.malakaishryock.repl.com")
```